# UnrealEngine - how to get buffer from in-memory image

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

In a c++ class in UnrealEngine, I have a runtime generated PNG image that I need to store in a buffer, to convert to a texture later.

What I miss is the step from my PNG in-memory image to a TArray buffer (**ima_buf** in the code below).

```
texture = FImageUtils::ImportBufferAsTexture2D(ima_buf);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note: This code is based heavily on code from Rama, well-known Unreal Forums' user and engine contributor

If you have your image as a buffer, and the buffer is in a `TArray<uint8>`, here is the function. In the .h:

```
#include "ImageUtils.h"
#include "IImageWrapper.h"
#include "IImageWrapperModule.h"

// in some class USomeClassOfYours (replace with needed name)
    static UTexture2D* LoadTexture2D_FromBuffer(const TArray<uint8>& RawFileData, EImageFormat ImageFormat, bool& IsValid, int32& Width, int32& Height);
```

And in the .cpp

```
UTexture2D* USomeClassOfYours::LoadTexture2D_FromBuffer(const TArray<uint8>& RawFileData, EImageFormat ImageFormat, bool& IsValid, int32& Width, int32& Height)
{
    IsValid = false;
    UTexture2D* LoadedT2D = nullptr;
    
    IImageWrapperModule& ImageWrapperModule = FModuleManager::LoadModuleChecked<IImageWrapperModule>(FName("ImageWrapper"));
    TSharedPtr<IImageWrapper> ImageWrapper = ImageWrapperModule.CreateImageWrapper(ImageFormat);
 
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      
    //Create T2D!
    if (ImageWrapper.IsValid() && ImageWrapper->SetCompressed(RawFileData.GetData(), RawFileData.Num()))
    { 
        TArray<uint8> UncompressedBGRA;
        if (ImageWrapper->GetRaw(ERGBFormat::BGRA, 8, UncompressedBGRA))
        {
            LoadedT2D = UTexture2D::CreateTransient(ImageWrapper->GetWidth(), ImageWrapper->GetHeight(), PF_B8G8R8A8);
            
            //Valid?
            if(!LoadedT2D) return nullptr;
            //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            
            //Out!
            Width = ImageWrapper->GetWidth();
            Height = ImageWrapper->GetHeight();
             
            //Copy!
            void* TextureData = LoadedT2D->PlatformData->Mips[0].BulkData.Lock(LOCK_READ_WRITE);
            FMemory::Memcpy(TextureData, UncompressedBGRA.GetData(), UncompressedBGRA.Num());
            LoadedT2D->PlatformData->Mips[0].BulkData.Unlock();

            //Update!
            LoadedT2D->UpdateResource();
        }
    }
     
    // Success!
    IsValid = true;
    return LoadedT2D;
}
```

If you need to import from file, add a second function that will use the functoin from above. Here is .h:

```
    /** Load a Texture2D from a JPG,PNG,BMP,ICO,EXR,ICNS file! IsValid tells you if file path was valid or not. Enjoy! -Rama */
    static UTexture2D* LoadTexture2D_FromFile(const FString& FullFilePath, EImageFormat ImageFormat, bool& IsValid, int32& Width, int32& Height);
```

and .cpp

```
UTexture2D* USomeClassOfYours::LoadTexture2D_FromFile(const FString& FullFilePath, EImageFormat ImageFormat, bool& IsValid, int32& Width, int32& Height)
{ 
    //Load From File
    TArray<uint8> RawFileData;
    if (!FFileHelper::LoadFileToArray(RawFileData, *FullFilePath)) return nullptr;
    
    return LoadTexture2D_FromBuffer(RawFileData, ImageFormat, IsValid, Width, Height);
}
```

For a `.png` image, you should use `EImageFormat::PNG` as the format input variable of course.

Comment: I have an image in memory, I could save and the reload it (to follow your code), but I'd prefer to avoid the I/O. So, my main concern is: how can I have a TArray<uint8> from an in-memory png image?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You don't need to save it if you already have it in memory. In what way is it stored in memory now? I assumed it's stored as `TArray<uint8>` because it's the most direct Unreal-native byte array type.

Comment: In the above function, `ImageWrapper->SetCompressed(X, Y))` is where you pass the buffer of the image. X is a pointer to the memory where it is, and Y is the number of bytes. You don't have to use TArray for this, it can be any memory whatsoever.

Comment: I didn't explain it right: I have an in-memory image from pyplot, just want to trasform it in  a buffer suitable for use in a code like: 
texture = FImageUtils::ImportBufferAsTexture2D(ima_buf);

Comment: Can you please describe the type of the `ima_buf` variable? I am not familiar with pyplot and its internals. If you provide more info, I will edit the answer to fit your exact problem, but without knowing anything about the type, I can't do that.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try to be more precise. Here are the details: I have an embedded (pybind11) python that creates a png image, rendered in memory as bytes. In my C++, I can read the globals() dict as a PyObject. Now here comes ima_buf: it is a TArray<uint8>. What I miss is how to go from my PyObject buffer to a TArray<uint8>.
Maybe should i edit the original question, to make it clearer?

Comment: Don't want to celebrate too soon, but maybe I solved with a call to PyObject_GetBuffer() with the right parameters. Still testing.

Comment: OK, I see. Yes, then the question should be like "how to access an image buffer created by `pybind` from a `PyObject` in C++?". The tags currently just include C++ and Unreal, but no mention of Python or pybind, even though it's actually what the main question is about.